# What documents are required to enter Poland with a dog from outside the EU?

Tags: paperwork, borders, eu, poland, pets

We are travelling by car from Moscow, Russia to Europe.

We will be crossing the Belarus-Poland borders, and a little dog (a yorkshire) is travelling with us.

Which documents do we need for the dog?

Answer (score 7):

Abstracted from [PetTravel.com](http://www.pettravel.com/immigration/poland.cfm) with tailoring to what I believe to be your requirements:

To enter Poland, your pet must first be microchipped with an ISO 11784/11785 pet microchip that is a 15 digit and non-encrypted. If your pet's microchip is not ISO 11784/11785 compliant, you can bring your own microchip scanner. A tattoo is an acceptable form of identification as long as it was given prior to July 3, 2011, is clearly visible and your pet's current rabies vaccination was administered after the tattoo was applied.

Your pet will need a rabies vaccination after the microchip is implanted and more than 21 days prior to entry but not more than the expiration date of the manufacturer of the vaccine. If it has a current rabies vaccination but no microchip, it will have to be vaccinated again after the microchip is implanted and wait 21 days before travel. Poland honours the three year rabies vaccination for dogs entering the country from outside of the EU.

As you are travelling with your pet and I assume are the legal owner of it, a licensed veterinarian must complete the Annex IV form for Poland within 10 days of entry. (Note: new form is required if issued by a licensed veterinarian after August 31, 2016.) and you or your representative must sign a Declaration of Non-Commercial Transport stating that your pet's transport does not involve the sale or transfer of ownership of your pet.

Your dog must be free of evidence of disease communicable to humans when examined at the port of entry to Poland. If your dog is not in apparent good health, further examination by a licensed veterinarian may be required at your expense.

Non-vaccinated puppies are not permitted to enter Poland.